# Can I avoid all these loops?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I have a grid with up to 52 weeks of pricing data as one big form. So left column is number of weeks, second is cost price, third is sales etc. etc. I start out with an index loop for the week numbers. In addition I have a query that pulls in the pricing, ie. weeks, cost_price,sales_price etc. I could have pricing for the 2,3,4,16,20 week rows and nothing else, or it could be all 52.

What is my best option to display the value for the input fields?

I can't use the index, because if I do something like #pricingInfo.cost_price[5]# it obviously will kick back based on index, which does not necessarily match the week number for that row (if I had a penny for how often I've wished for something like this to work based on value btw?!).

Right now I have it coded to loop over the query for each value and if the week number matches the index loop week number, do the output. See example code below. There's a few more columns than what shows here - think we'll end up with 5 total.

The only other option I can think of is to expand the query so it is always 52 rows, matching the index loop, and then use the index output. This might be better? I am after all doing column count * 52 cfloops here, and if I build out the query, I would do a loop or two whilst doing that, but be done after that?

```
<form>
<cfloop from="1" to="52" index="i">
    <input name="weeks_#i#" value="#i#" />
    <input name="net_local_#i#" value="<cfloop query='selectPrices'><cfif selectPrices.weeks eq i>#selectPrices.net_local#</cfif></cfloop>" />
    <input name="booking_fee_#i#" value="<cfloop query='selectPrices'><cfif selectPrices.weeks eq i>#selectPrices.booking_fee#</cfif></cfloop>" />
</cfloop>
</form>
```

Am I completely overlooking a better way?! Going live on Lucee, dev setup is CF.

Comment: Build your query `selectPrices` the same way as your table. Have 52 rows and each row has the 5 mentioned columns with prices. Then do a single loop on `<cfloop query="selectPrices">`. It's not clear to me, if you want to display all weeks regardless of data or just the weeks that already have data.

Comment: Hi Alex, this is actually exactly what I have now ended up doing after playing with it a bit more after posting here. I do display the other rows with 0 values for now, but might just leave them blank. When building the query, I use a valuelist of the week columns from selectPrices and listFind to only loop through selectPrices when needed. This ended up feeling the most efficient. I'd give you the points if this wasn't a comment, and thanks again for confirming this way of approaching it was a good one. Knew that first setup wasn't ideal!

Comment: Use your database to get a table of consecutive dates.  If you don't have a calendar table already, which is exactly that, your google search string is `sql subquery to create consecutive dates`.  Once you have that figured out, you can left join to your other table to get your rows with 0 values.